# A question of permanent function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permanent

Let $A, B, A-B$ be positive definite matrices. How to show $\mathrm{per} A\ge \mathrm{per} B$? Here $\mathrm{per}$ is the [permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) function.

Also, if $A$ is $n\times n$ doubly stochastic matrix which is also positive semidefinite. Let $J$ be the matrix with all entries $1/n$. How to show $A-J$ is also positive semidefinite?